# display a table field in a list using condition

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have table x that contains id and name fields.
I want to display the id when I select the name in the list.

I wrote this but it doesn't work.
The error msg is: either BOF or EOF or current record has been deleted.
Requested operation requires a current record.

I think simply the default record is record 1, so what's wrong ?!

```
Dim con As Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset
Set con = CurrentProject.Connection

rs.Open "select id from tbl where namen = '" & list1.ListIndex & "'", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
ttt.SetFocus
ttt.Text = rs!id
```

---

thank you so much pteranodon for your help
I changed the code to be like this

```
Private Sub list1_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "select id from tbl where namen = '" & list1.Value & "'"
ttt.SetFocus
ttt = DLookup("id", "tbl", "namen='" & list1.Value & "'")
rs.Open strSQL, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
End Sub
```

but I got this msg
operation is not allowed when the object is open ?

I didn't add the items to the list1 by using vba code I just followed the window that show up after adding the list1 to the form cus I also have problem with code

if you please can you add the complete code 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the value of the listbox, not ListIndex. ListIndex contains a number, the zero-based index of the current selection in the listbox. You are passing in something like `select id from tbl where namen = '13'` Since no records match, you get that error message.

I really reccommend using a string to hold any constructed SQL so that you can debug it easily. If you had

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "select id from tbl where namen = '" & list1.Value & "'"
Debug.Print strSQL
rs.Open strSQL, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

it would be easier to read and much easier to debug. Also, you'll want to check for rs.BOF and rs.EOF right after opening a recordset:

```
If Not (rs.BOF Or rs.EOF) Then
    'Do stuff
Else
    'No records in recordset
End
```

Unlike VB textboxes, you can't use .Text in VBA textboxes unless the textbox has the focus. Use `ttt.Value` (or just `ttt` instead).

And if you are only looking up a single value like this you can replace all of your code like this:

```
Private Sub list1_Click()
    ttt = DLookup("id", "tbl", "namen='" & list1.Value & "'")
End Sub
```

Using DLookup instead of manually opening a recordsest yourself. I would also go back through the listbox wizard. If you put the id in the first column and the name in the second, then hide the first column (the wizard will help you do this), the list will **show** the name but **store** the id. Then you don't even need the extra textbox. The id is stored in `List1.Value` and the name is available as `List1.Column(1)`.

Comment: I've added new comments above, about a little problem :)